# Knock gem: Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms) for Post Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems

I am using [knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) gem with rails api only application. I follow its documentation and when i make a curl post request or using postman for getting token i get not found with 404 status. Please help me where i am doing wrong.
any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: are you passing the username and password as parameters in the body form-data?

Comment: no i am passing data in JSON format like this
{
"auth":{
 "email": "foo@bar.com", 
 "password": "secret"
 }
}
using postman.
i am using has_secure_password in user model with name,email,password_digest columns in users table.

Answer (score 0):

Knock send 404 when passed credentials is wrong.

Can you check whether the thing is working when you pass correct credentials?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you are trying to send payload (may be via Postman) like this:

```
auth['email']:abc@gmail.com
auth['password']:11111111
or
auth[email]:'abc@gmail.com'
auth[password]:'11111111'
or
auth['email']:'abc@gmail.com'
auth['password']:'11111111'
```

It will be ok if you remove comma encapsulation around keys and value, right format is:

```
auth[email]:abc@gmail.com
auth[password]:11111111
```